# Prove that $\overline{\mathrm{Int}\,(\overline{\mathrm{Int}\,A})} = \overline{\mathrm{Int}\,A}$

Tags: general-topology

I need to proof this statement, and I don't know where to start.

*In every topological sapce, we have that $\overline{\mathrm{Int}\,(\overline{\mathrm{Int}\,A})} = \overline{\mathrm{Int}\,A}$*

I tried to show that $\mathrm{Int}\,(\overline{\mathrm{Int}\,A})$ is closed, but I don't know how.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: The interior of a closed set is not necessarily closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** One inclusion is fairly straightforward (use $\operatorname{Int}B \subseteq B$). For the other, show that $\operatorname{Int}A \subseteq \operatorname{Int}(\overline{\operatorname{Int}A})$.